# Can I get the filepath if I have the UUID?

Tags: openstack, uuid

I've seen questions about how to find out the UUID, given the file path.

But what about the opposite? Can I find out the file path if I have the UUID? Do UUIDs reference the address location somehow?

Why am I asking this?

Because I've read this snippet about Openstack's Swift and am wondering if this concept applies to UUIDs in general:

> Rather than the traditional idea of referring to files by their
>   location on a disk drive, developers can instead refer to a unique
>   identifier referring to the file or piece of information

In which context then, would I be able to use the identifier (e.g. SQL queries)?